# Ajax on button click, but no forms involved

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, button

I would like to make an Ajax call on a button click, but I do not want the button placed within a form.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Ajax doesn't involve forms. It's basically a request that you create yourself to the server - either GET or POST. Make the request and pass whatever data you need to

Answer (score 1):

Use this bit of code

```
<button onclick=function()>Button</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible:

```
<form action="example.com" method="post">
...
</form>
<button name="button" id="button">Submit</button>
```

Way 1: use jquery selector and bind an event.

```
$('#button').click(function(e) {
    //--> actions here
});
```

Way 2: or call a function in the button:

```
<button name="button" onclick="javascript:action();">Submit</button>
```

There's a lot to choose from.